# Do mathematicians consider functional integration to be good mathematics? If so, what is it?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I am trying to learn about path integration in physics and, from what I understand, this means learning to do functional integrals. (Note: I know what a functional is and I also have done functional differentiation.)

But I went to the Wikipedia page and also did some googling and came up with nothing intelligible that explained (as far as I could see) what a functional integral was and how to do it. This either means info about it is hard to find or I am not understanding it.

I am physicist who is wary of the way some physicists do mathematics. Example: the Dirac delta function isn't a function at all but has something to do with distributions. So is the notion of a functional integral a legitimate mathematical concept? If it is, can you also explain what it is and/or provide a reference so I can learn about it myself.

EDIT:

Question:

Would a bounty help this question get answered?

Comment: More or less, functional integrals are integrals of functions defined on function spaces. The problem is in making sense of this; in some contexts we know how to do it, in others, we do not.

Comment: Interesting. Your last remark was not apparent from anything I read. But it certainly would explain why there seemed to be only remarks on particular types of functional integrals and nothing on them in general.

Comment: @MarianoSuarezAlvarez Would a bounty help this question get answered? I am new to SE, so I don't know how useful they are.